# android: How to get NFC tag ID using EasyNFC

Tags: android, nfc

I have an NFC passive tag and want to get the unique ID of the tag using [EasyNFC](https://github.com/Mobisocial/EasyNFC) library. How to do this?

Usually the library passed `[NdefMessage][2]` that contains an array of `[NdefRecord][3]` but not sure what they means exactly plus the documentation and sample app aren't so clear in this.

Comment: What do you mean by one one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, configure `EasyNFC` in exchange mode like this  in `onCreate()`

```
mNfc = new Nfc(this);
mNfc.enableExchangeMode();
```

Then on `onNewIntent()`, you can get it.

```
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (mNfc.onNewIntent(this, intent)) {
        Log.i("Foreground dispatch", "Discovered tag with intent: " + intent);
        Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        tag.getId(); // <---- AWESOME !!!
        NdefMessage newMessage = prepareNdefMessage();
        boolean result =writeNdefMessageToTag(newMessage, tag);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: what will be inside preparedNdefMessage an writeNdefMessageTo Tag??

Comment: please check the documentations of the library.

Comment: could u please provide link of the documentation